# Staque, stack which can add int numbers to bottom and top also

Tags: c++, stack, queue

I`m trying to make queue or stack like structure, in which I can add and delete int numbers to/from bottom and top.

If input int is even(%2 = 0) then add it to Top, and if odd(%2 = 1) then add to bottom.

I was trying to make it using Node class which got only data and next(pointer to next Node object) but for that reason I cant add or delete int to top, only to bottom.

That's an Header file:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    #ifndef myStaque
    #define myStaque

    class Staque
    {
     public:
        Staque();
        Staque(const Staque & a);
        bool ifEmpty() const;
        void push(const int& b);
        void print() const;
        int top() const;
        int bottom() const;
        void delKenti();
        void delLuwi();
        Staque& operator= (const Staque& a);
     private:
        class Node
        {
        public:
            int data;
            Node* next;
            Node* previous;
            Node(int a, Node* c = 0, Node* b = 0): data(a), next(c), previous(b){}
        };
        Node* myTop;
        Node* myBottom;
    };
    #endif
```

And there's cpp that I was trying to make it work(but it's not working):

```
    #include "myStaque.h"
    #include <new>
    using namespace std;

    Staque::Staque()
    {

    }
    Staque::Staque(const Staque& a) {
        *this = a;
    }
    Staque& Staque:: operator= (const Staque& a) {
        Staque::Node* ptr;
        for (ptr = a.myBottom; ptr != 0; ptr = ptr->next)
        {
            myTop = a.myTop;
            myBottom = a.myBottom;
        }
        return *this;

    }

    bool Staque::ifEmpty() const
    {
        return (myBottom == 0);
    }
    void Staque::push(const int& b)
    {
        if (ifEmpty()) {
            myBottom = new Staque::Node(b, 0);
            myTop = myBottom;
        }
        if (b % 2) {
            Staque::Node* tmp;
            tmp = new Staque::Node(b, 0);
            myTop->next = tmp;
            myTop = tmp;
        }
        else {
            myBottom = new Staque::Node(b, myBottom);
        }

    }
    void Staque::print() const
    {
        Staque::Node* ptr;
        for (ptr = myBottom; ptr != 0; ptr = ptr->next)
            cout << ptr->data << ", ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    void Staque::delLuwi() {
        if (myBottom->data % 2 && myTop->data % 2) {
            cout << "Bottom and top are kenti " << endl;
        }
        else {
            if (!(myBottom->data % 2)) {
                myBottom = myBottom->next;
            }
            else if (!(myTop->data % 2)) {
                Staque::Node* tmp;
                tmp = myBottom;
                while ( !(tmp->next = 0) ) {
                    tmp = tmp->next;
                }
                myTop = tmp;
                myTop->next = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    void Staque::delKenti() {
        if (!(myBottom->data % 2) && !(myTop->data % 2)) {
            cout << "Bottom and top are kenti " << endl;
        }
        else {
            if (myBottom->data % 2) {
                myBottom = myBottom->next;
            }
            else if (myTop->data % 2) {
                Staque::Node* tmp;
                tmp = myBottom;
                while (!(tmp = nullptr)) {
                    tmp = tmp->next;
                }
                myTop = tmp;
                myTop->next = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use what's already provided: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue , https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack

Comment: This looks like it's for educational purpose so this won't be much immediate help, but [`std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque).

Comment: But in Stack class i cant add it to Bottom, there`s only one function push, which adds it to top

Comment: @JesperJuhl I one never implements anything on it's own, how could he ever become a good programmer?

Comment: Recommendations: 1: Stop thinking ins stack. As soon as you can operator on both ends you don't have a stack. You need different thinking. For one thing you need two push methods, one for top and one for bottom. Or since we're trying to not think in stack terms, one for front and one for back. You'd also want two pops.2: write this class and test it before worrying about the application logic, the evens go on one end and the odds on the other. If you build your staque so it only does what you need it to do right now, it'll be harder to reuse later.

Comment: 3: break it down even further. Write a and test a generic linked list that does all the usual linked list stuff and write staque so that it uses the linked list. Now you have a linked list, a staque, and a  tool that adds evens on one end and odds on the other.

Comment: General advice: Start with a plan. Ask yourself, "What do I need to?" Then write down your answer. Break the answer up into steps. Break those steps down into steps. Keep going until you have a collection of small building blocks you can easily write and assemble into the program. If you don't know how to do something, make it a bunch of smaller problems and attack the smaller problems.If you find you have to do the same sort of thing in many steps, generalize it and make everyone use the same thing. Odds are really good with small steps that someone's already written it.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you so much for your answer, i`ll try doing this

Comment: What you have there is a [double-ended queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue).

Answer (score 0):

I somehow did it, that code is terrible, but i got no time to make it good, if someone`s interested there it is:
Header:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    #ifndef myStaque
    #define myStaque

    class Staque
    {
     public:
        Staque();
        Staque(const Staque & a);
        bool ifEmpty() const;
        void push(const int& b);
        void print() const;
        int top() const;
        int bottom() const;
        void delKenti();
        void delLuwi();
        Staque& operator= (const Staque& a);
     private:
        class Node
        {
        public:
            int data;
            Node* next;
            Node(int a, Node* c = 0): data(a), next(c){}
        };
        Node* myTop;
        Node* myBottom;
    };
    #endif
```

---

and cpp:

```
#include "myStaque.h"
#include <new>
using namespace std;

Staque::Staque()
{

}
Staque::Staque(const Staque& a) {
    *this = a;
}
Staque& Staque:: operator= (const Staque& a) {
    Staque::Node* ptr;
    for (ptr = a.myBottom; ptr != 0; ptr = ptr->next)
    {
        myTop = a.myTop;
        myBottom = a.myBottom;
    }
    return *this;

}

bool Staque::ifEmpty() const
{
    return (myBottom == 0);
}
void Staque::push(const int& b)
{
    if (ifEmpty()) {
        myBottom = new Staque::Node(b, 0);
        return;
    }
    if (myBottom->next == 0) {
        if (b % 2) {
            myTop = new Staque::Node(b, 0);
            myBottom->next = myTop;
        }
        else {
            myTop = myBottom;
            myBottom = new Staque::Node(b, myTop);

        }
    }
    else {
        if (b % 2) {
            Staque::Node* tmp;
            tmp = new Staque::Node(b, 0);
            myTop->next = tmp;
            myTop = tmp;
        }
        else {
            myBottom = new Staque::Node(b, myBottom);

        }
    }
}
void Staque::print() const
{
    Staque::Node* ptr;
    for (ptr = myBottom; ptr != 0; ptr = ptr->next)
        cout << ptr->data << ", ";
    cout << endl;
}
void Staque::delLuwi() {
        if (ifEmpty()) {
        cout << "Staque is empty" << endl;
        return;
    }
    if (myBottom->data % 2 && myTop->data % 2) {
        cout << "Cant delete Luwi number Bottom and top are kenti " << endl;
    }
    else {
        if (!(myBottom->data % 2)) {
            myBottom = myBottom->next;
        }
        else if (!(myTop->data % 2)) {
            Staque::Node* tmp;
            tmp = myBottom;
            while ( tmp->next != myTop ) {
                tmp = tmp->next;
            }
            myTop = tmp;
            myTop->next = 0;
        }
    }
}
void Staque::delKenti() {
    if (ifEmpty()) {
        cout << "Staque is empty" << endl;
        return;
    }
    if (!(myBottom->data % 2) && !(myTop->data % 2)) {
        cout << "Cant delete Kenti number Bottom and top are Luwi " << endl;
    }
    else {
        if (myBottom->data % 2) {
            myBottom = myBottom->next;
        }
        else if (myTop->data % 2) {
            Staque::Node* tmp;
            tmp = myBottom;
            while (tmp->next !=myTop) {
                tmp = tmp->next;
            }
            myTop = tmp;
            myTop->next = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Tsu shi swavlob shen albat...  mgoni mushaobs es cade aba

#include
#include

using namespace std;

struct node {       //vqmnit node struqturas
int info;
struct node* next;         // next pointeri miutitebs shemdeg elementze
};

class StackQueue {

private:
struct node* head;
int size;

public:

```
struct node* createNewNode(int);   //vqmnit xal nodes

void insertAtFront(int);   //winidan damateba

void insertAtLast(int);      // uknidan damateba

void deleteFromFront();        // winidan washla

void deleteFromLast();           //uknidan washla

void displayList();          //stack queues bechdva

StackQueue() {

    head = NULL;
    size = 0;
}
```

};

struct node* StackQueue::createNewNode(int value) {  //vqmnit axal nodes

```
struct node* temp;

temp = new(nothrow) (struct node);
temp->info = value;
temp->next = NULL;

return temp;
```

}

void StackQueue::insertAtFront(int value) {         //winidan vamatebt

```
struct node* temp, * p;

temp = createNewNode(value);

if (head == NULL) { // es aris mashin roca stack queue carielia pirveli elementi emanteba

    head = temp;
    head->next = NULL;
}

else {             //aq chveulebisamebr shegvaqvs

    p = head;
    head = temp;
    head->next = p;
}

cout << "\nElement inserted at front successfully.";
size++;
```

}

void StackQueue::insertAtLast(int value) {           //uknidan damateba

```
struct node* temp, * s;

temp = createNewNode(value);

if (head == NULL) {          //pirveli elementis damateba
    head = temp;
    head->next = NULL;
}

else {               // danarcheni elementebis damateba
    s = head;

    while (s->next != NULL) {

        s = s->next;
    }

    temp->next = NULL;
    s->next = temp;
}

cout << "\nElement inserted at end successfully.";
size++;
```

}

void StackQueue::deleteFromFront() {

```
if (size == 0) {
    return;
}
    
struct node* s;
s = head;

if (head == NULL) {           //tu ukve carielia vegar amovshlit da vprintavt am mesijs

    cout << "\nThe staque is Empty";
    return;
}

if (s->info % 2 == 0) {              // tu luwia ishleba
    head = head->next;
    free(s);

    size--;
    cout << "\nEven element deleted.";

    if (size == 0) {
        head = NULL;
    }
}
```

}

void StackQueue::deleteFromLast() {         //uknidan washla

```
if (size == 0) {
    return;
}

struct node* s, * temp;
s = head;

if (head == NULL) {              //carielis shemtxvevashi shemdegi mesiji
    cout << "\nThe staque is Empty";
    return;
}

do {
    temp = s;
    s = s->next;
} while (s != nullptr);

if (s->info % 2 == 1)     {      // tu ar aris luwi anu kentia vshlit
    temp->next = NULL;
    free(s);
    size--;
    cout << "\nOdd element deleted";
    if (size == 0)
        head = NULL;
}
```

}

void StackQueue::displayList() {           //vbechdavt sias am stekis

```
struct node* temp;

if (head == NULL) {
    cout << "\nThe staque is Empty";         //tu carielia amasac vbechdavt
    return;
}

temp = head;

cout << "\nElements of staque are: ";

while (temp != NULL) {
    cout << temp->info << " ";
    temp = temp->next;
}
cout << endl;
```

}

Comment: SO is an English-only site.